# RAD and Websphere: How to deploy a war/binary as opposed to the Java code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

Is there a way to just deploy a war in websphere when using RAD?  If you already have the binary.

Rad / 7.5, Websphere6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no menu option that is available in RAD which allows you to deploy a WAR from within RAD to WAS.

You can try this as an alternative. Export the WAR to a Hotdeploy directory (WRD - WebSphere Rapid Deployment). You need to start the WRD monitor services and any WAR or EAR that is deployed to this directory gets automatically installed in the server.

Check if this meets your requirement(s)

Manglu

Answer (score 1):

In RAD, you can create a new server without 'adding' an ear project to it.  After you do that, start up the server.  From the server view in RAD, right click on your server config, select 'run administrative console'.  From there you can use the websphere admin tools to deploy a binary just like you would in regular old full-blown WAS.  There's a 'wizard' available to do that located in the 'Applications' menu item called 'Install new application'.  Hope that helps.